# Angular ng new installing forever

Tags: node.js, angular-cli

After installing Node.JS and using the ng new command, it runs all the downloads but stops at CREATE app/e2e/src/app.po.ts! Then it will just infinitely say Installing Packages!

I'm not sure why it is doing this, can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Try installing it

```
npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular
```

Answer (score 0):

When executing Angular CLI be sure you have enough free memory as ng run over npm and both can be very expensive specially in memory use.

You could have this problem because your PC doesn't have enough memory to handle the build.

It happened the same to me, getting stuck for around 8 to 10 minutes, then I tried again closing all unnecessary apps and it works. Anyway my Dev PC is quite old, slow.